# Given that X and Y are RV supported on [2,3], If the correlation coefficient of X^t and Y^s is 0 for any s,t ∈ [2,3], then X and Y are independent.

Tags: probability, statistics, independence, correlation, moment-generating-functions

I am doing a probability course HW and run into trouble with the following problem:
Given that X and Y are RV supported on [2,3], If the correlation coefficient of X^t and Y^s is 0 for any s,t ∈ [2,3], then check if X and Y are independent.
The homework hint says we may need to consider the moment-generating function to solve this problem, while I have no idea at all.
I know that if the correlation coefficient is 0, then E(X^t*Y^s)=E(X^t)E(Y^s), but I do not know how to link this equation with moment generating function and independence. Could anyone give a hand on this?

Comment: Any (s,t) is ambiguous.  One particular pair or all pairs?

Comment: Are you sure $s,t$ are in the range $[2,3]$? You mention this is the support of $X,Y$...

Comment: Yes, my HW does say that both the support of X, Y and range of s,t is [2,3]. and I think it refers to all pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall $Z_1,Z_2$ are independent if and only if their joint MGF is the product of their individual MGFs:

$$E[e^{t_1Z_1+t_2Z_2}]=E[e^{t_1Z_1}]E[e^{t_2Z_2}].$$

To show $X,Y$ are independent, it suffices to show $\ln X,\ln Y$ are independent. Can you show $\ln X,\ln Y$ are independent using the uncorrelated condition and MGFs?

Comment: I am still a little confused, could you add more details on that plz?

Comment: Show $\ln X$ and $\ln Y$ are independent using the MGF characterization. Can you try this?

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @W.A no prob. feel free to accept the ans if it helps